# Detect unused CSS in a dynamic single-page app?

Tags: html, css, templates, single-page-application

How can I detect unused CSS rules in a single-page application with many templates?
I know about **dust-me-selectors plugin** and **Chrome Audits**, but this tools work with static pages.
Maybe some local script to find .class in templates, and class actions (addClass(), removeClass(), .etc) in JS files?